# Django add to ManyToMany on create

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

so basically I want to mimic the admin page behavior when adding objects to a m2m field, and i must admit... I'm way too lost... at the moment each model has it's own view, but if I add a button to the create objects for the Album model, how do I return the Photo models to the Album view so I can save them?

My models.py:

```
class Photos(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to="Resources/"
    )

class Album(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(
        Photos
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - you are not using the default admin interface, and you want to add photos when you create an album, assuming the photos are already uploaded (because either the photos or the album have to exist first) - in the album view.

You could create a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) for creating the album, like so:

```
class AlbumCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['title', 'files']
```

You can display this form in the Album view, and by default it will generate a CharField for title and a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) for files, and you can pass in a queryset Photos.objects.all(). The ModelMultipleChoiceField has a default widget SelectMultiple, which is basically:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

in HTML.

In your view, you would collect the request.POST data in the model form and save it. See more about saving ModelForms [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).